# Azure Bot Dynamic Input Fields

Tags: botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards, bot-framework-composer

Can we add & delete input fields dynamically in an Adaptive Card?

We need to have button called as "Add New", as user clicks on button it should keep adding input fields along with a delete button next to it.

We are using composer based bot with .Net SDK for bot development.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anyway to do exactly what you are seeking. But perhaps some combination of [ShowCard](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ShowCard.html) and [ToggleVisibility](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ToggleVisibility.html)?

Either way, it will be done via the adaptive card. No way to do this in the bot framework side (unless you are using a channel that supports updating/replacing an entire activity in which you would just send a whole new card).